# how to display image in div data-setbg attribute in cakephp 3

Tags: php, html

The html code is below:

```
<div class="hs-item set-bg" data-setbg="bg.jpg"></div>
```

I want to display the image above data-setbg in cakephp 3

I have tried:

```
<?php $URL = WWW_ROOT."img/bg.jpg"; ?>
<div class="hs-item set-bg" data-setbg="<?php echo $URL; ?>"></div>

<div class="hs-item set-bg" data-setbg="<?php echo $this->Html->image('bg.jpg'); ?>"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

i have found answer of my question

my problem was to display image in data-setbg attribute

Answer is